# Page Navigation on Windows Phone 8 using HTML/JavaScript/Apache Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8, cordova

I have some problems with page navigation using Windows Phone 8 with Apache Cordova 3.0.
I tried different ways to solve this problems but it still does not work.

At first i tried to use forms to navigate to another page.

```
<form action="CreateUser.html" method="get">
        <input class="buttons"  name="btnCreateUser" type="submit" value="Create User" />
</form>
```

When i click on the button the page can not be found. The CreateUser.html page is in the same directory. If i use a Browser (Chrome/IE) it works.

When i change the action to http://www.google.com both options (Browser and Phone) work.

I also tried to navigate to another page by using JavaScript. Here is my code:

```
function get(httpUrl) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", httpUrl, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Now i use onclick="get("CreateUser")" event of the button but there is no reaction.
Both in the browser and on the mobile device.

The only thing that worked for me is the window.location feature. But it seems that i can't transform informations on the next page with that way.

Is there any opportuinity to navigate between those two pages and transfer some information?
Or did i just something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The CreateUser.html page" if i'm correct you are using AJAX to read file (page) contents and paste them in HTML?

If yes, then read this:

2.1.    Cross-domain problem

Before making AJAX request you must allow cross-domain requests and core support, by setting:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
```

Those must be set in a specific-phonegap function “DeviceReady”, example:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: "www/about.txt",
                dataType: 'text'
            }).done(function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                });
            });
```

2.2.    url

Making Windows Phone 8 oriented application, in AJAX request you MUST specify full path to resource, example:
                    url: "www/about.txt",

Making Windows Phone 8 oriented application, in AJAX request you MUST NOT specify full path to resource, example:
url: "about.txt",

2.3.    Source File extensions

Be careful using unknown extension files, like template extension *.tpl or similar. Sometimes AJAX doesn’t like them, I suggest using simple *.txt and *.html extensions.